# Configuring fs_default connection in Airflow

Tags: config, airflow

I would like to configure the `fs_default` connection of Airflow, basically to make sure paths will always be resolved from the same starting point (the root of my directory/repository).

I set up my airflow home with `export AIRFLOW_HOME=./airflow_home`. Therefore I have a directory `airflow_home` at the root of my project.

And then I put this in my `airflow.cfg`:

```
[core]

# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository. This path must be absolute.
dags_folder = ./airflow_home/dags

fs_default_conn = ./airflow_home/../

# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = ./airflow_home/logs
```

I did a `airflow resetdb` followed by `airflow initdb`, and then started the webserver (and the scheduler). I went into Admin > Connection to check if my changes were taken into account, but apparently not. The `fs_default`connection still has this in the Extras field:

```
{"path": "/"}
```

Any idea how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create Connection using Airflow UI / CLI or by an environment variable. It won't work by adding it to `airflow.cfg` file.

Check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-the-ui on how to create a connection.